# MVC controller path in VS vs live on production not the same with ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In javascript when I click a link I do an ajax call to:

/Process/Add

When running from Visual Studio it works great. When I publish to the server I get a javascript error saying it can't find:

```
http://servernamehere/Process/Add/
```

It should be looking for it in:

```
http://servernamehere/MyApp/Process/Add/
```

Why is it that in VS it knows to include MyApp to the path but on the server it doesn't?

```
function addRecord() {
            var name = $("#name").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Process/Add/",
                type: "post",
                data: { firstname: name },
                success: function(data){
                    location.reload();
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Can you post relevant code?

Comment: The version from Vs doesn't have the MyApp path.

Comment: I agree, but how do I make this work because on IIS I give my app that name and so that's the url it has. This is not the default website on IIS and I don't have the option to make it the default.

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode URL period.
Floremin http://stackoverflow.com/a/23618327/3373870 answer should give you what you looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to render the URL in the your Javascript code so it includes app root:

```
url: '@Url.Action("Add", "Process")'
```

Comment: So what you have there includes app root? Is the Url.Action() function doing that?

Comment: Yes. It will render the correct route to the action in the controller. This is preferred method to render URLs because it will still work even if you change the way routing is done. You just have to make sure the javascript code is within a Razor view, so this gets rendered. It will not work if your Javascript is in a separate JS file.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit difficult to answer this without a look at some of your code. Typically, however, this is because when running locally your site is treated as a top level site, meaning it's not under "Default Site/[MY_SITE]. So your paths are fine.

When you publish out to the server however, your javascript code has no idea that it's not/may not be a top level site.

We have this problem internally and we've taken to the following pattern in our javascript. We have an init routine to our javascript libraries.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var apiPath = "@HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath";
        MyLibrary.Init(apiPath);
    });
</script>
```

Then in the init method we attached the pathing as needed. So int our init method:

```
var apiParticipantPath = "/PATH/TO/REST/ENDPOINT";

var init = function(appRoot) {

if (appRoot !== "/") {
    apiParticipantPath = appRoot + apiParticipantPath;
}
```

and then finally in use

```
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: apiParticipantPath,
    data: {
        --STUFF
    },
    dataType: "text"
})
.done(function() {
    --STUFF
})
.fail(function() {
    --STUFF
})
.always(function() {});
```

If you use a pattern like this, it doesn't matter if you're using a top level site or a virtual directory underneath something like DEFAULT_SITE. It's also nice because you can keep your javascript libraries separate and not have to embed them into your views to get @Url.Action to work.

I'm guessing this is what your issue is. If not, let me know and we can delve further.

Comment: Downvote explanation please. This solves the problem the same way as above except without mixing large quantities of js and razor view code.

Comment: If somebody is using a different route template, or if the default (`{controller}/{action}/{id}`) template is changed in this project, then your method will not work without updating the JS code. On any but trivial projects such bug would be very difficult to discover especially since it's an Ajax call and the effects are not obvious to a non-developer tester. This is not mixing large quantities of JS and Razor code - it's one line. You have a good point on keeping the JS code in separate files. My method would not work in that case.

Comment: Your `apiParticipantPath` is assigned a hard coded value which depends on how routing is setup.